# Easy Repro UI Automatid testing test fails. with error LoginPage' threw an exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-crm, easyrepro

I trying to use EasyRepro https://github.com/microsoft/EasyRepro/tree/releases/OnPremise to automate UI testing for our on premise Customer Relationship Management site part of the Dynamic 365 apps.

What I have tried so far is running the sample test which comes with the EasyRepro as well as using an ADFS login function. I have also tried the later and earlier branches of the Easy Repro and the on premise branch, since I am using an on premise version of CRM. I ensured the drivers were installed and that I am using the correct versions as well that they are all compatible.

What happens is the google chrome browser opens up to the CRM website then meets the login page. Nothing happens till the test times out after about 3 minutes.

Specs

Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

Google Chrome v74

Windows Server 2012 R2

CRM Version 1612 (8.2.2.112) on-premises

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/60056050/7920473