# How to automatically login using EasyRepro in Dynamics 365 on-premise

Tags: automated-tests, dynamics-crm, devops, dynamics-365, easyrepro

I'm trying to do Automated UI Testing using EasyRepro in Dynamics 365 On-Premise. I managed to the testing with one issue, I can't automatically login to my Dynamics 365 Organization. Below are the code that I used:

```
var client = new WebClient(TestSettings.Options);
            using (var xrmApp = new XrmApp(client))
            {
              xrmApp.OnlineLogin.Login(_xrmUri, _username, _password);
              xrmApp.Navigation.OpenSubArea("My Work", "Companies");
              xrmApp.CommandBar.ClickCommand("New");
              xrmApp.Entity.SetValue("name", TestSettings.GetRandomString(5,15));
              xrmApp.Entity.Save();
             }
```

When I run it, the newly open chrome page will still ask me to put my credential, after I enter my credential (the CRM username/password), the script will run smoothly.

Since, I plan to use this as part of our automated testing. Is there any way for the EasyRepro to automatically login?

Comment: In Easyrepro, xrmBrowser is for On-Premise and xrmApp for UCI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/EasyRepro/issues/513) talks about the login part for on-premise CRM instance automatic login scripting.

> This is how I got around Windows Authentication Login (Could not use the ADFS Login on our On-Premise CRM Install). Just defined the Login elements:

```
using (var xrmBrowser = new Browser(TestSettings.Options))
{
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String xpath = "//*[@id='search']";
// String logoffcrm = "#navBarUserInfoTextId > span.navTabButtonUserInfoText.navTabButtonUserInfoCompany";
Actions keyAction = new Actions(xrmBrowser.Driver);
xrmBrowser.GoToXrmUri(_xrmUri);
xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox")).SendKeys(_username);
xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(1000);
xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordTextBox")).SendKeys(_password);
xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(1000);

            try
            {
                if (_browser == "Chrome")
                {
                    xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_SubmitButton")).Click();
                }

                if (_browser == "IE")
                {
                    xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_SubmitButton")).Submit();
                }

                xrmBrowser.Driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.XPath(xpath)
                        , new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60),
              e => { xrmBrowser.Driver.WaitForPageToLoad(); },
              f => { throw new Exception("Login failed."); });
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                //old element has gone

                //Console.WriteLine(g);
                xrmBrowser.Driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.XPath(xpath)
                       , new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60),
             e => { xrmBrowser.Driver.WaitForPageToLoad(); },
             f => { throw new Exception("Login failed."); });
            }
```

I hope you are, but make sure you are using [EasyRepro Release Branch - OnPremise](https://github.com/microsoft/EasyRepro/tree/releases/OnPremise) repo.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you can add credentials in `app.config` like so:

```
<add key="OnlineUsername" value="name@name.onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="OnlinePassword" value="*********" />
<add key="OnlineCrmUrl" value="https://org.crm.dynamics.com/" />
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro

Comment: Have tried it, but still requires me to login by prompting the login dialog. It work if I try to login to Dynamics 365 Online, however for Dynamics 365 On Premise it's still not working..